# How to get PHP to be able to read system environment variables

Tags: php, centos, environment-variables

I am using PHP as PHP-FPM on Centos. I am trying to follow the http://12factor.net/ guidelines of having the settings be stored in environment variables.

I have created a file in /etc/profile.d that sets the environment variables I want, and the environment variables appear when tested in the CLI via Bash i.e. running the bash script:

```
echo $SOME_SERVER_SETTING
```

shows the correct output.

I have set the clear_env setting to false and variables_order to `EGPCS`, however, the variable I have set does not show up in PHP either `getenv('SOME_SERVER_SETTING')` or doing `var_dump($_ENV)`

What other setting needs to be set to allow PHP-FPM to receive all of the server environment variables, and in particular those set through a shell script in /etc/profiles.d on Centos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Security reasons :-)

See `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (debian location, may be different on CentOs)

```
; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
;clear_env = no 

; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment.
; Default Value: clean env
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Comment: I said in the question that I have set clear_env to no already.

Comment: Did you really set it to "no"? In your initial post you wrote "false".
I only get USER and HOME env vars but if I set clear_env = no in above file I get TERM PATH PWD etc. as well

Comment: I was setting it through php_admin_value[clear_env] - which is why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 26):

Tested on Centos 7 with Systemd service and PHP 5.6.4

OPEN

```
/etc/php.ini
```

FIND

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

REPLACE TO

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
# http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order
```

OPEN

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf (maybe /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf)
(do not confuse with /etc/php-fpm.conf)
```

FIND IF EXIST

```
clear_env = yes
```

REPLACE TO OR ADD

```
clear_env = no
# http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php
```

OPEN

```
/etc/environment
```

ADD

```
#any variables you need, for example:
MY_VAR=1234
```

RUN IN SHELL FOR CHECK

```
source /etc/environment
echo $MY_VAR # 1234
```

RUN IN SHELL

```
ln -fs /etc/environment /etc/sysconfig/php-fpm
systemctl daemon-reload && service php-fpm restart
```

...TESTING

OPEN

```
index.php # in your project folder, running with php-fpm
```

ADD

```
var_dump(getenv('MY_VAR'), $_ENV['MY_VAR']);exit;
```

RUN IN BROWSER

```
http://mylink.to.project/index.php   
string(4) "1234"
string(4) "1234"
```

ENJOY!

Comment: hmm, but you are hard-coding the variable inside /etc/environment here. Why no add with export=val instead of hard-coding it?

Comment: It's up to you, this is an example

Comment: saved my week :)

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables in a FastCGI setup are set as input by the client of the FPM process, for instance NginX. They are sent as headers to the FastCGI server, which interprets them and sets them accordingly for you to read out with getenv.

If you are in fact using NginX, look for the fastcgi_param directives. You can also set environment variables in your pool config of php5-fpm, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the environment variables from the correct location. PHP creates a super global variable for this: `$_ENV` So you can access a single variable by accessing a certain element from that variable, which holds an array: `echo $_ENV['SOME_SERVER_SETTING'];`

I have no idea why your example above should work on CLI. The super global variable is the documented location and works.

What might be your issue here is that the variables are not set for the http server process. Typically scripts like those in `/etc/profile.d` are executed at login time. So when a user creates a session inside the system. But that will never happen for an http server started as a system server. No login is performed, no profile script is executed, no environment variables are set.

To solve this you can

- set the environment variables inside the startup script of the service
- set the variables inside the host configuration or `.htaccess` style files
- auto-prepend a script setting the variables

Comment: I clarified - that was testing with Bash in the CLI not PHP. Can you expand on "set the environment variables inside the startup script of the service". I'm testing while logged into the server, and am restarting PHP-FPM through the init.d script. I would have thought that would bring the environment variables in, as the PHP-FPM process is launched from the logged in root process. Also, just calling the script that sets the env variables in the init.d script appears to make no change.

Comment: The environment variables set in your personal session are (usually) not handed over to the process you start via some init script, since that service is executed under another user account. And even if that would be the case it would not really solve your issue, since under normal circumstances you would not manually start the service. Instead it would be started by the boot sequence where no login has occurred too. That "root process" has not performed any login, as you put it.

Comment: I guess you are right about the fact that setting the variables in the startup script won't work... Otherwise running that script manually would hand over the variables which apparently is not the case. Though... not sure, actually. Have a try "exporting" them in addition to just setting them.