# Lumen does not read env from system during request

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, docker, environment-variables, lumen

Lumen 5.4, MySql & Docker. I have following variables in global `env`

```
$ printenv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=database
etc
```

`.env` in my project the are present also, but they have different values.

If I type in tinker `env('DB_HOST')`, it prints value from the global environment, but when application runs, it takes from the specified `.env` file. I think the problem exists within following function in `Laravel\Lumen\Application` :

```
/**
 * Load a configuration file into the application.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return void
 */
public function configure($name)
{
    if (isset($this->loadedConfigurations[$name])) {
        return;
    }

    $this->loadedConfigurations[$name] = true;

    $path = $this->getConfigurationPath($name);

    if ($path) {
        $this->make('config')->set($name, require $path);
    }
}
```

How to override those values or make it to avoid those conditions: `isset($this->loadedConfigurations[$name])` ?

Comment: You don't reference the `env()` you instead reference a `config()` file and handle the logic of a global vs local env in there. You should never reference the `.env()` file directly.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Of course you're right, but in this situation it's not the case. I use  Docker's system `env's` and I only want to override those values in my local `.env` by the given values in Docker's environment. The case is how to avoid auto-loading configuration mentioned above.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822695/how-to-get-php-to-be-able-to-read-system-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

I still think that, regarding my comment, the answer remains the same. If you wish to utilize the docker environment variables as opposed to your local .env variables, then the config directory is still the way to go. In this case, it looks like you wish to target the `database host`. So let's do that:

In your `config/database.php` file, change the following:

```
'mysql' => [
    //...
    'host' => getenv('DB_HOST') ?: env('DB_HOST', 'defaultvalue')
]
```

Then only make reference to the host through the config file.

```
config("database.mysql.host");
```

You will get the ENV from your docker container if it exists, otherwise you will get the `DB_HOST` declaration from your `.env` file.