# PHP Can't Access Docker Environment (env) Variable

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, containers

This might be a dumb question, but since I can't find a solution that works for me, here goes.

I have a docker image built from **debian 11** with **apache** and **php 8.1** installed.

I start the container with something like:

```
docker run -e MY_ENV_VAR=VALUE myphpimg bash
```

Once inside the container, I run "**php -i**" and can see all env variables, including "**MY_ENV_VAR**"

[image: php -i return]

All good, right? Nope. If I try to acess the env variable inside a php script it simply does not work. I tried "**getenv**" as well as "**$_ENV**" and "**$_SERVER**".

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly is PHP used from Apache HTTP Server (CGI, FastCGI, in a different way)?

Comment: Check if there is a built-in [PassEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) option in the settings of the Apache HTTP Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Worked for me:**

After days of messing around I got it to work but didn't fully understand it.
My original image, built "*from*" debian 11 with apache and php 8.1 installed, had the following entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT service apache2 restart && bash
```

I changed it to:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D BACKGROUND && bash
```

It worked.

I now believe that on start all docker environment variables are passed to apache, but if you restart apache for some reason you'll loose access to the variables. I Know that because after everything was working fine I restarted apache.

I ended up manually adding the env vars that I pass to docker to /etc/init.d/apache2:

[image: edit /etc/init.d/apache2]

Now everytime apache runs the env vars are passed on, even on restart. However, I must use "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" instead of "service apache2 start".

**Bonus:**

If you need to use $_ENV instead of getenv() edit "variables_order" in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Common solution (php configuration):

```
clear_env = no
```

Related configurations: [How to get PHP to be able to read system environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822695/how-to-get-php-to-be-able-to-read-system-environment-variables)